# React - Redux - this.props.fetch.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Im getting the error **this.props.fetch.map is not a function** when i try to pass my data via **mapStateToProps** to my component. If i console logo my **Action** im getting an **Object** .I dont know what to do pass this object as an array. Could some on help me ?

This is my component **trabalhos.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';


class Trabalhos extends Component {

    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.fetchData();
    }


    renderList(){

        return _.map(this.props.fetch.trabalhos ,() => {

            return(

                <li key={this.props.fetch.trabalhos.miristica.id}>
                    <img src={this.props.fetch.trabalhos.miristica.img} /> 
                    <p>{this.props.fetch.trabalhos.miristica.descricao}</p>
                    <p>{this.props.fetch.trabalhos.miristica.nome}</p>            
                </li>

            );
        });
    }

    render(){
    return (

        <div>
            <div className="trabalhos">
                <div className="trabalhos_caixa">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-12">
                            <ul className="no_pad">
                                {this.renderList()}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}


function mapStateToProps(state){

return { fetch: state.fetch };

}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Trabalhos);
```

This is my action index.js

```
import Firebase from 'firebase';
import { FETCH_DATA } from './types';

var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/database");

var config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyDi3f9pSGH833Hq3TBzibCK1SbPOheiGmE",
authDomain: "portofoliofirebase.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://portofoliofirebase.firebaseio.com",
storageBucket: "portofoliofirebase.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "656734450041"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var data = firebase.database().ref();

export function fetchData(){
return dispatch => {
    data.on('value', snapshot => {
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_DATA,
            payload: snapshot.val()
        });
    });
};
}
```

This is my reducer **fetch_reducer.js**

```
import { FETCH_DATA } from '../actions/types';

export default function(state = [], action) {
console.log(action);
switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_DATA:
        return action.payload;
}

return state;
}
```

This is my rootReducer **index.jx**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import fetchReducer from './fetch_reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({

fetch: fetchReducer

});

export default rootReducer;
```

Store **index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import reducers from './reducers';
import routes from './routes';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
</Provider>
, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Thank You !

Comment: where did you assign `state.fetch`'

Comment: hello, Hitmands, sorry but i dont understand what you mean !! state fetch came from my rootReducer.

Comment: post the code where you create the `state.fetch` property.

Comment: @Hseleiro are you sure that fetch in store is an array not object or anything else. Map is not native function of Object but only Array

Comment: @Hitmands, do you mean my fetch_reducer ? it in my question

Comment: @magnat , yes i think the problem is that, because it gets me an object and not an array, and i dont know how to do it to pass it from object to array and use map on it...i dont know even if my logic is correct, pass object to array and map it. Thanks

Comment: @Hseleiro but do you always get one object or more? If only one object why do you want to map it? If there can be an array of objects try to pass this one object to array

Comment: @Hseleiro or maybe you want to "map" through all keys of this object?

Comment: When i console log my action, i receive an object in my payload, inside that object i got another object call trabalhos(works), inside trabalhos i got another 2 objects whit the names of that works, then i get the keys, id , name etc... Im seeing this on my console when i console log my action ! i want to retrieve that names and ids .

Answer (score 1):

I guess that initial state of Redux store is empty in your case. I mean that render fires before any reducer fires, so this.props.fetch === {}

Please specify preloadedState at [createStore](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html).

I.e. replace (at Store index.js)

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);
```

with

```
const store = createStore(reducers, {fetch:[]}, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk))
```

Comment: I got it working, i will update my component for you to see what i have done.Thanks anyway !!

Comment: see my component trabalhos.js

Comment: it is not about your component or action or reducer or rootReducer. It is about your redux store which code you did not posted.

Comment: Ia have post it now. Updated !! Thank You !

Comment: but its not working like your answer, i dont know if your solution works.